# Vectors, Vector Lines

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Find the equation of the line passing through a point $B$, with position vector $\mathbf{b}$ relative to the origin $O$, which is perpendicular to and intersects the line $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{a} + \lambda \mathbf{c}$ where $\mathbf{c} \ne \mathbf{0}$, given that $B$ is not a point of the line.

No idea how to approach question. Is it that the dot product of line passing through $B$ and $\mathbf{r} =\mathbf{0}$?

Comment: My, my, you are a slow learner, dear Shem.  **Don't abuse this site and/or its users.**

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ is not on $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{a}+\lambda \, \mathbf{c}$, then $\mathbf{b} \ne \mathbf{a}$.

The point of intersection is given by

\begin{align*}
  0 &= (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{b}) \cdot \mathbf{c} \\
  0 &= \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{c}+\lambda \, c^2-\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{c} \\
  \lambda &= \frac{(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}) \cdot  \mathbf{c}}{c^2}
\end{align*}

So the equation of the required line is

$$\mathbf{r}=
\mathbf{b}+\mu
\left[
  \mathbf{a}-\mathbf{b}+
  \frac{(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}) \cdot  \mathbf{c}}{c^2} \, \mathbf{c}
\right]$$

or equivalently in case of $\mathbb{R}^3$,

$$\mathbf{r}=
\mathbf{b}+\frac{\mu \, \mathbf{c} \times [(\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{b}) \times  \mathbf{c}]}{c^2}$$

Comment: For your last equation, how do you know that you‘re working in $\mathbb R^3$, so that cross products are defined?

Comment: @amd Just in case

Comment: Thanks alot, can i just ask why is the required line [a-b+......} just confused about the -b part

Comment: It passes through $B$ pointing in direction $\mathbf{a}+\lambda \, \mathbf{c}-\mathbf{b}$.